# Сделать кроссдоменный запрос к бекэнду

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с кроссдоменным запросом. Я расположил бекенд на одном сервере, а фронтэнд на другом. Теперь при помощи ajax-запроса фронтэнд-скрипт не может получить данные из бекэнда

Вот адрес, по которому можно получить данные:

```
http://zlodiak.pythonanywhere.com/days/1497104260/1497968260
```

[Тут лежит](https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/8xgoq437/3/) мой скрипт, который отправляет ajax-запрос по вышеуказанному адресу. ajax-запрос отправляется после того как пользователь в первом датепикере выбирает дату '2017-06-01', а во втором датепикере выбирает дату '2017-06-30'. Затем нажимает кнопку субмита

В результате консоль говорит о том, что кроссдоменный запрос не разрешён:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/days/1496264400/1498770000. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Я [пробовал](http://zlodiak.pythonanywhere.com/) располагать на одном сервере и фронтэнд, и бекэнд. При этом всё описанной проблемы не было и связка работала без проблем. Но мне нужно чтобы фронтэнд и бекенд находились именно на разных серверах

Comment: 1) Не у верен, что jsfiddle правильно видит ваш `127.0.0.1`. Пропишите ваш домен явно. 2) Убедитесь, что установили нужные заголовки  https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно чтобы ваш сервер хотя бы [отдавал заголовок CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Ещё лучше чтобы он отдавал конкретные хосты, откуда можно делать запрос.

Например, для web2py это делается так:

```
if request.env.http_origin:
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.env.http_origin
```

Вы можете ограничить условием для каких хостов такой заголовок будет, для каких - нет.